# VHDL concatenate different types

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl, concatenation

I have the follwing existing FPGA code

```
fpga_avr32_data       : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);

SIGNAL read_sensor                       : INTEGER;

TYPE meas_type IS ARRAY (7 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
TYPE meas_reg_type IS ARRAY (NATURAL RANGE <>) OF meas_type;



fpga_avr32_data <= "0000" & meas_reg(read_sensor)(read_channel)
```

--

I want to replace "0000" with the lowest 4 "bits" of read_sensor, something like this

```
fpga_avr32_data <= read_sensor(3 DOWNTO 0) & meas_reg(read_sensor)(read_channel)
```

Is this possible ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But not the way you do it. `read_sensor` is an integer while `fpga_avr32_data` is a `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`, so you must first convert the integer into a vector:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
signal rsv: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
...
rsv <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(read_sensor, 32));
```

And then extract the 4 LSBs:

```
fpga_avr32_data <= rsv(3 DOWNTO 0) & meas_reg(read_sensor)(read_channel);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for your quick answear, it passed compilation, let me test it as well